# Template struct inside a template struct

Tags: c#, struct

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
public struct Pair<T,U> {
    public readonly T Fst;
    public readonly U Snd;

    public Pair(T fst, U snd) {
        this.Fst = fst;
        this.Snd = snd;
    }

    public override String ToString() {
        return "(" + Fst +", " + Snd + ")";
    }
}
```

Now I need to declare the variable "appointment" of a type `Pair<Pair<int,int>, String>`.

1. how do I initialize it?
2. how do I access appointment.Fst.Snd? (Its type should be int)

Comment: as a side point, C# generics are _not_ the same as C++ templates, even though they look the same. They behave entirely differently!

Comment: If you're using .NET 4, you might want to use the built-in `Tuple` type(s) instead of making your own `Pair`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure to understand where the problem is. Doesn't this work?

```
Pair<Pair<int, int>, string> s = new Pair<Pair<int, int>, string>(new Pair<int, int>(5, 10), "hello");
 Console.WriteLine(s.Fst.Snd);
```

Comment: I'd much prefer to have a `Pair.Create` method (just like `Tuple.Create`) and use `var` to make the code cleaner/clearer/shorter: `var s = Pair.Create(Pair.Create(5, 10), "hello");`

Answer (score 0):

Initialisation can be done like this

```
Pair<Pair<int, int>, String> appt = new Pair<Pair<int, int>, string>(new Pair<int,int>(1,3),"test");
```

Then you can access:

```
appt.Fst; // type pair<int,int>
appt.Snd; // type string
appt.Fst.Snd; // type int
```